# How to create objects using rails polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, polymorphic-associations

I want to create objects using Polymorphic association but it returns me error like:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass):
```

Here are params:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TAQdqSTXAFCrq6yZBUnjVXe7IsPqmxuLh/qM/2QvKaVvsfP
/Sy6VNF7H38IzOg8aMj39t6HR+aZLLtyj8uMzyw==", "search"=>"Newport-Mesa Unified 
School District", "id"=>"32", "type"=>"PrivateSchool", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Here are models:

```
class PrivateSchool < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :popular_schools, as: :resource, :dependent => :destroy
end

class PopularSchool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :popular_schools, as: :resource, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Controller code:

```
def index
    @popular_school = PopularSchool.new
    @popular_schools = PopularSchool.all
  end

  def create
    @popular_school.new.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: `@popular_school` in `nil` in `create` action. Instead it should be `@popular_school = PopularSchool.new(params)`

Comment: @Deep Do we need to define params again? It is polymorphic and it should work automatically as I am not submitting other params. Could you please explain?

Comment: You are not defining the params. The `params` is the data you receive from the view. So using that data you will create a new object and save it in database. The `@popular_school` you created in the `index` action is no longer available in any other `action`, that will only be available in the view.

Comment: Even after using polymorphic we need to define params again in private method? How I could fix it then? I have only 2 things in params. I just want to save `, "id"=>"32", "type"=>"PrivateSchool"` in db.

Comment: The record is being created but `"id"=>"32", "type"=>"PrivateSchool"` is not saving in db. the code is: `@popular_school = PopularSchool.new(name: params[:name])
    @popular_school.save` could you please?

Comment: @Deep if you want to see please: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132711/disacussion-between-learningror-and-junan-chakma

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `@popular_school` variable anywhere. That's why you are getting `NoMethodError (undefined method new for nil:NilClass):` error.

Try `PopularSchool.create(your_params)`

Comment: it says : `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
`

Comment: Could you show us the `form` where from you are submitting to create `PopularSchool`?

Comment: `<%= form_for([:admin, @popular_school]) do |f| %>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, "", id: "search-txt", class: "ui-autocomplete-input form-control" %>
          <div class="results" id="search-results"></div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "id", "", value: "" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "type", "", value: "" %>
          <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn btn-md btn-info" %>
<% end %>`

Comment: The record is being created but `"id"=>"32", "type"=>"PrivateSchool"` is not saving in db. the code is: `@popular_school = PopularSchool.new(name: params[:name])
    @popular_school.save` could you please?

Comment: With out refactor the form may be you can try like this `@popular_school = PopularSchool.new(id: params[:id], type: params[:type]) ` then save it like `@popular_school.save`

Comment: it says `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'type' for PopularSchool.):` I have `resource_id integer,
  resource_type character varying,` in db.

Comment: Then try it `@popular_school = PopularSchool.new(resource_id: params[:id], resource_type: params[:type])` then save it like `@popular_school.save`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132711/discussion-between-learningror-and-junan-chakma).